# Input to reshape is a tensor with 61440 values, but the requested shape has 1024

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, nlp

I am creating a classifier with GRU and attention mechanism. The training dataset has 255 training feature vectors and has binary (0/1) label data.

train = (1000, 255)

label = (1000, ) ->{0/1}

**About Model**

The GRU takes the training data as input (work as an encoder), the attention mechanism would be performed by taking all the hidden units of encoder per time step, then the context vector (attention + output hidden state of the encoder) pass through a softmax layer for prediction.

```
max_len = 255

BATCH_SIZE = 60
embedding_dim = 256
units = 1024
vocab_train = len(train_token.word_index)+1


class Attention(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, units):
        super(Attention, self).__init__()

        self.s = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units, kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.L2(0.001))
        self.t = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units, kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.L2(0.001))
        self.a = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.L2(0.001))

    def call(self, query, value):
        #query: (None, 255, 1024)
        #value: (None, 1024)
        
        query = query[0, :]
        value = tf.expand_dims(value, 1)[0, :]
        #prev: (255, 1024)
        #value: (1, 1024)
        
        score = self.a(tf.keras.activations.relu(self.s(query) + self.t(value)))
        
        attention_weights = tf.keras.activations.softmax(score, axis=1) 

        attention = attention_weights * value
        
        attention = tf.reduce_sum(attention, axis=0) 

        return attention, attention_weights

attention = Attention(units)


# encoder 
encoder = tf.keras.Input(shape=(max_len, ))
enc_embd = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_train, embedding_dim)(encoder)
encoder_gru = tf.keras.layers.GRU(units, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.L2(0.001))
output_e, hidden_e = encoder_gru(enc_embd)

# attention
attention_value, attention_weights = attention(output_e, hidden_e)

# reshaping to concatenate the attention and hidden_e layer
attention_value = tf.reshape(attention_value, (1, attention_value.shape[0]))
hidden_e = tf.reshape(hidden_e, (1, hidden_e.shape[1]))

context_vector = tf.concat([attention_value, hidden_e], axis=1)

attention_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1*context_vector.shape[1], activation='relu')
attention_ = attention_layer(context_vector)

# final output layer
final_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='softmax', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.L2(0.001))
output_f = final_output(attention_)



model = tf.keras.Model(encoder, output_f)

print(model.summary())

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train, label, batch_size=60, epochs=10, verbose=1)
```

ERROR

```
InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument:  Input to reshape is a tensor with 61440 values, but the requested shape has 1024
     [[node model_11/tf.reshape_51/Reshape (defined at <ipython-input-336-3c6515bf3e82>:1) ]]
     [[gradient_tape/model_11/embedding_42/embedding_lookup/Reshape/_38]]
  (1) Invalid argument:  Input to reshape is a tensor with 61440 values, but the requested shape has 1024
     [[node model_11/tf.reshape_51/Reshape (defined at <ipython-input-336-3c6515bf3e82>:1) ]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_51709]

Function call stack:
train_function -> train_function
```

Comment: As the error says, you're trying to reshape an array with 61440 values into an array with a different number of values, and that's impossible. What's your question?

Comment: I want to remove the error. Where the reshaping is happening?

Comment: You have several lines of code that literally contain the word "reshape", maybe there. If you comment them out and everything below them, does it work? Did you post the error message in its entirety?